# Does $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{3^nn!}{n^n}$ converge?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

> Does  $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{3^nn!}{n^n}$ converge?

I believe it diverges, but I'm having trouble finding a good series with which to compare it.

Comment: Try ratio test. This diverges.

Comment: When dealing with this sort of problem, it would be helpful to have a [list of convergence tests](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_tests) in mind.

Answer (score 6):

Let $a_n=\frac{3^nn!}{n^n}$. Then
$$ \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\frac{3(n+1)n^n}{(n+1)^{n+1}}=3\Big(\frac{n}{n+1}\Big)^n$$
hence
$$ \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=3\lim_{n\to\infty}\Big(\frac{n}{n+1}\Big)^n=\frac{3}{e}>1$$
Therefore the series diverges by the ratio test.

Comment: Nicely done!  (+1)

Answer (score 2):

Using Stirling's approximation for $n!$, we get

$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{3^nn!}{n^n} 
\sim  
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{3^n}{n^n}{\sqrt {2\pi n}}\left({\frac {n}{e}}\right)^{n} 
= 
\sum_{n=1}^\infty {\sqrt {2\pi n}}\left({\frac {3}{e}}\right)^{n},
$$
which obviously diverges.